# Change color of SKSpriteNode if i click on "touches began" return the colors that i had clicked

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

if i click on "Touches Began" i need to change the SKShapeNode color, for example. Click the color of SKShapeNode change to red, click again color change to blue, after all clicks, the color return to the first color creating one loop of color. How can i do this ? Swift 3.0 Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create an array with all the colors you want, in order.
- Create an integer variable to keep track of current color.
- Modify the integer on `touchesBegan` and assign a new color to your `SKShapeNode` properties: `strokeColor` and/or `fillColor`, depending on what you want.

Code example using a circle as a `SKShapeNode`:

```
// An array with all the colors you want
let colors = [UIColor.redColor(),UIColor.blueColor(),UIColor.greenColor()]
// An integer to keep track of the current color
var actualIndex = 0

var myShapeNode : SKShapeNode!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    super.didMoveToView(view)
    myShapeNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
    myShapeNode.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2)
    addChild(myShapeNode)
    myShapeNode.strokeColor = colors[actualIndex]
    myShapeNode.fillColor = colors[actualIndex]
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    actualIndex = (actualIndex+1)%colors.count //Goes back to 0 when reaches colors.count

    myShapeNode.strokeColor = colors[actualIndex]
    myShapeNode.fillColor = colors[actualIndex]
}
```